# unable to generate allure report for protractor cucumber

Tags: protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I'm trying to generate allure report for protractor cucumber but it is not generating any report.

**conf.js** is as below

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
    },

    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

    specs: [
        'sample.feature'
    ],

    restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,

    cucumberOpts: {
        require:[
            'sampleStep.js', 
            'reporter.js'
        ],
    },

    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
    },
};
```

and the **reporter.js** file is

```
var reporter = require('cucumberjs-allure-reporter');

reporter.config(
   //targetDir:'./allure-results/'
   { targetDir : './Reports'}
);
module.exports = reporter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cucumberjs-allure-reporter` library doesn't support higher Cucumber (I can't remember the exact version, maybe only supports Cucumber 2 and lower).

You can try this new library, [cucumberjs-allure2-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumberjs-allure2-reporter), which is compatible with Cucumber.JS 3+ and Allure 2+.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm getting the following error while using this solution[20:00:49] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[20:00:49] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file conf.js
[20:00:49] E/configParser - TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventBroadcaster' of undefined
    at Reporter.CucumberJSAllureFormatter [as constructor] (C:\Users\pc\node_modules\cucumberjs-allure2-reporter\dist\src\CucumberJSAllureReporter.js:54:17)